# How to change every email value in a table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I work with Zend Framework 1.12 and MySQL. In my database I have 4k rows, and all have a unique e-mail value.

How should I change this value for every row? Is it better to use a PHP script or to use a MySQL query?

Example of desired result:

[image]

Comment: You want to change every value to one value or what?

Comment: If the email is unique why does you need to change it {email}+1@gmail.com ?

Comment: Because I want to checku one feature and I don't want to send email to users. This database is not mine and I can't delete rows, but I can change emails to tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a PHP script that makes use of Zend Framework, eg:

```
$data = array(
    'email'      => $myNewEmail,
);

$n = $db->update('users', $data, 'user_id = ' . $userId);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Comment: This not solve my problem but after thinking about it one more time it was useful. Thanks

Comment: Great glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I anybody have the same question I show you my action to hide user emails.

```
public function hideMailsAction()
    {
        $usersTable = new User_Table();
        $k = 0;
        foreach($usersTable->fetchAll() as $user)
        {
            $userId = $user['user_id'];
            $usersTable->update(['user_email' => 'mymail+'.$k.'@gmail.com'], 'user_id ='.$userId);
            $k++;
        }
    }
```